# Is there any way to disable tooltip if values are not available ? Right now it is showing the tooltip from the nearest point if values are not there

Tags: highcharts, tooltip, react-highcharts

```
`Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'column',
  },
  tooltip: {
    shared: true,
    formatter: function() {
      return this.points.reduce(function(s, point) {
      
        return s + '<br/>' + point.series.name + ': ' +
          point.y + '%';
      }, '<b>' + this.x + '</b>');
    },
  },
  series: [{
    data: [null, 30, 5, null, null, 30]
  }, {
    data: [null, 30, 55, null, null, 33]
  }, {
    data: [null, -12, 25, null, null, 23]
  }, {
    data: [null, -3.0, 10, null, null, 23]
  }, {
    data: [null, 7, 100, null, null, 23]
  }],


});
`
```

When I hover on the 3 or 4 xAxis, it shows the tooltip for 5 xAxis.

[Please refer the jsfiddle code](https://jsfiddle.net/1oqwL7pa/)

I am expecting, if we don't have any **Y** value for any of **x**, no tooltip should display on hover for that particular point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `stickyTracking` property, which needs to be disabled:

```
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      stickyTracking: false
    }
  }
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/t27gfbr1/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.stickyTracking

Comment: is there any way to disappear tooltip after hovering valid xAxis.
For example, first i hover on 3 xAxis then i hover on 4 xAxis. but tooltip for 3 xAxis remain open.

Comment: Hi @Hitesh Jain, The best way will be to disable `shared` option and build the tooltip in this way: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/sLbv6t8n/ If it doesn't work for you, I will try to find some other solution.